# How to force inner join in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

I would like to ask why Entity Framework 6 automatically translate Include (with where condition) to LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, and is there any option to change it?

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserGroup>> GetUserGroupWithUser()
{
    var UserIds = new List<int>{ 1};

    var userGroups = await context.UserGroups.Include(userGroup => 
     userGroup.UserToUserGroups.Where(ugtu => ugtu.IsActive && 
     UserIds.Contains(ugtu.UserId)))
     .ThenInclude(ugtu => ugtu.User)
     .Where(userGroup => userGroup.UserToUserGroups.Any())
     //Removed some projection
     .ToListAsync();

     return userGroups;
}
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[IsActive], [u].[Name], [t].[Id], [t].[IsActive], [t].[UserGroupId], [t].[UserId], [t].[Id0], [t].[IsActive0], [t].[Name]
FROM [UserGroups] AS [u]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [u1].[Id], [u1].[IsActive], [u1].[UserGroupId], [u1].[UserId], [u2].[Id] AS [Id0], [u2].[IsActive] AS [IsActive0], [u2].[Name]
    FROM [UserToUserGroups] AS [u1]
    INNER JOIN [Users] AS [u2] ON [u1].[UserId] = [u2].[Id]
    WHERE ([u1].[IsActive] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([u1].[UserId] = 1)
) AS [t] ON [u].[Id] = [t].[UserGroupId]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [UserToUserGroups] AS [u0]
    WHERE [u].[Id] = [u0].[UserGroupId])
ORDER BY [u].[Id], [t].[Id]
```

**Entities:**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserToUserGroup> UserToUserGroups { get; set;}
}

 public class UserToUserGroup
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int UserGroupId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
 }

public class UserGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserToUserGroup> UserToUserGroups { get; set; }
}
```

**Configuration:**

```
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Users");
        builder.HasKey(user => user.Id);
        builder.Property(user => user.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}

public class UserGroupConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserGroup>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserGroup> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("UserGroups");
        builder.HasKey(userGroup => userGroup.Id);
        builder.Property(userGroup => userGroup.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}

public class UserToUserGroupConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserToUserGroup>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserToUserGroup> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("UserToUserGroups");
        builder.HasKey(ugtu => ugtu.Id);
        builder.Property(ugtu => ugtu.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.HasIndex(ugtu => new
        {
            ugtu.UserId,
            ugtu.UserGroupId
        }).HasFilter("IsActive = 'true'").IsUnique();

        builder
            .HasOne(utug => utug.User)
            .WithMany(user => user.UserToUserGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(ugtu => ugtu.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        builder.HasOne(utug => utug.UserGroup)
            .WithMany(user => user.UserToUserGroups)
            .HasForeignKey(ugtu => ugtu.UserGroupId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
[image]

**Checked**

1. I tried with IsRequired() inside the configuration.

Thanks in advance for all responses.

Comment: Use a newer version of EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it with join command [linq-joining-operator-join](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-joining-operator-join) .

I put the generated query

```
  var UserIds = new List<int> { 1 };

        var query = context.UserToUserGroup
        .Join(
            context.UserGroup,
            UserToUserGroup => UserToUserGroup.UserGroupId,
            UserGroup => UserGroup.Id,
            (UserToUserGroup, UserGroup) => new { UserToUserGroup, UserGroup }
        )
        .Join(
            context.Users,
            UserToUserGroup =>
            UserToUserGroup.UserToUserGroup.UserId,
            Users => Users.Id,
            (UserToUserGroup, Users) =>
            new { UserToUserGroup, Users }
        ).Where(p=>p.UserToUserGroup.UserToUserGroup.IsActive && UserIds.Contains(p.UserToUserGroup.UserToUserGroup.UserId)) .ToListAsync();
```

Query:

```
SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[IsActive], [u].[UserGroupId], [u].[UserId], [u0].[Id], [u0].[IsActive], [u0].[Name], [u1].[Id], [u1].[IsActive], [u1].[Name]
FROM [UserToUserGroups] AS [u]
INNER JOIN [UserGroups] AS [u0] ON [u].[UserGroupId] = [u0].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Users] AS [u1] ON [u].[UserId] = [u1].[Id]
WHERE [u].[IsActive] = CAST(1 AS bit) AND [u].[UserId] = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Entity Framework bases its joins on the design of the database, so in this case it's forcing a `LEFT JOIN`.

Instead do the joins manually

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserGroup>> GetUserGroupWithUser()
{
    var UserIds = new List<int>{ 1};

    var userGroups = await
        (from ug in context.UserGroups
         join ugtu in UserToUserGroups on ug.UserId equals ugtu.UserId
         where ugtu.IsActive
         where UserIds.Contains(ug.UserId)
         select whatever
        )
        .ToListAsync();

     return userGroups;
}
```

Comment: First answer is wrong, you are not able to .Where(ug => UserIds.Contains(ug.UserId)) because ug does not contain UserId